# Align div to a table column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've spent days trying to find the solution of my problem.

I would like to align a  or a  to a specific column of my table.

For example for [my sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6hVXE/1/) :

```
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>Test</div>
```

I would like to align my test  below the 2.2 cell.

I'm using Jquery.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hVXE/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var position = $("#test").position();

  $("div").css({
    "left": position.left
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**DEMO 1** http://jsfiddle.net/YrHXF/ (using css only)

If you dont want to add width in CSS thn using jquery
**DEMO 2** http://jsfiddle.net/4Nzfr/

```
div,table{
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: why are you setting the width as 100px? what will happen if table data changes

Comment: Its a rough figure. Its can be changed according to requirement.

Comment: acha he. but how is my solution? It will not depend on the size of data

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your table and that div and then define the width and text-align:

```
<div class="wrap">
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>Test</div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hVXE/2/)

Comment: Or he can give the same class name to both.

Comment: @tripless if you would like, you need not to put your div outside the table but keep them in a tr like this demo which is best solution without defining the width: http://jsfiddle.net/6hVXE/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<center>` Tag. Why do you write extra code unnecessary? :)

```
 <center>    
       <table border="1" >
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>1.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>2.2</td>
                <td>2.3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>Test</div>
    </center>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
   <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>2.2</td>
            <td>2.3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>Test</div>
</div>

.container{
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set the style in your corresponding css, or use as u please :)

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <table border="1" style="width:100%" >
        <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>2.2</td>
            <td>2.3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="text-align:center;">Test</div>
    </div>
```